# Loki: make not found (trying to update Realtek drivers)

Tags: internet, ethernet

Just installed Loki on a desktop with a Realtek (RTL8111/RTL8168) ethernet card, and the LAN does not work. Apparently this is an issue with the card, so to fix it I went to:

[How To get your Realtek RTL8111/RTL8168 working (updated guide)](https://www.unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/)

and downloaded the driver manually from my laptop (since I have no internet connection on that PC). Now, to install it I need to first blacklist the old driver with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo blacklist r8169 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'
```

which worked, and then simply:

```
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

The problem is that this results in:

```
./autorun.sh: 30: ./autorun.sh: make: not found
```

which is [apparently fixed with](https://superuser.com/questions/192683/sh-make-not-found):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

but I have no internet connection to do that!

Am I doing something wrong? Is it really this difficult to get LAN internet connection with Loki using a Realtek card?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about that. Just download the .deb file from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/r8168-dkms/download) and then install it on the other pc with `sudo apt install ./r8168*.deb`

That version is for Loki only. If you decide to use Juno you'd need to download [this version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/r8168-dkms/download)